# counting mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, count

I have the following code

```
$result = $handle->select()->from('store_products_id', array('count'=>'COUNT(store_products_id.product_id)'))
                                       ->where('store_products_id.store_id=?', $this->store_id)
                                       ->columns($selectColumns)
                                       ->join('product_quickinfo', 'store_products_id.product_id = 
                                              product_quickinfo.product_id')

                                       ->join('image_paths', 'product_quickinfo.image_id = 
                                              image_paths.image_id')

                                       ->order('product_quickinfo.date_created DESC')
                                       ->limitPage($this->page_number, $this->sum_each_page)
                                       ->query(ZEND_DB::FETCH_OBJ);
```

However, I only get back one result.. here's a look at the print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 14 [small_path] => 1 [product_name] => v evrecvrv [price] => 22 [product_id] => 1 [image_id] => 1 [date_created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [large_path] => [description] => ) )
```

When I remove the COUNT controller, I get all the items back.
How can I both count the entire query (beyond the LIMIT that I impose) and also get the entire query back?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, this issue is not particular to Zend Framework.  It's an issue with using aggregate functions in SQL queries.  In a single query, you can either get the aggregate, or the pre-aggregated data rows, but not both.

Comment: This is similar to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983419/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-records-from-a-query-with-zend-framework/984283#984283) that I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is simply to run two queries, in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Since MySQL 4.0.0 you can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your query which will tell MySQL to count total number of rows disregarding LIMIT clause. You still need to execute a second query in order to retrieve row count, but it’s a simple query that just retrieves the stored row count.

Usage is pretty simple. In you main query you need to add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option just after SELECT and in second query you need to use FOUND_ROWS() function to get total number of rows. Queries would look like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name, email 
FROM users 
WHERE name LIKE 'a%' 
LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The only limitation is that you must call second query immediately after the first one because SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS does not save number of rows anywhere.

(Copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846047/count-in-a-query-with-multiple-joins-and-a-group-by-clause))

Comment: Interesting article, I was not aware of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. The comments in the cited article suggest it is no more performant, as the full row set is still calculated (i.e. no LIMIT optimisation), though it's definitely neater to call FOUND_ROWS() rather than a big query again.